# RelayMutation expects prop to be data fetched by Relay, adding mutation to query not working

Tags: relayjs

I am getting the error:

```
bundle.js:28169 Warning: RelayMutation: Expected prop `group` supplied to `AddBlock` to be data fetched by Relay. This is likely an error unless you are purposely passing in mock data that conforms to the shape of this mutation's fragment.
```

It might seem similar to the problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769922/relay-mutation-expects-data-fetched-by-relay), but the answer (of making sure the mutation is added to the initial query) is not working as a solution for me. I already have the mutation in the original query.

Here is my relevant code:

```
export class AddBlock extends Relay.Mutation {
    getMutation() {
        return Relay.QL`mutation { addBlock }`;
    }

    getVariables() {
        return {
            body: this.props.body
        };
    }

    getFatQuery() {
        return Relay.QL`
            fragment on AddBlock {
                newBlockEdge,
                group {
                    blocks
                }
            }
        `;
    }

    getConfigs() {
        return [{
            type: 'RANGE_ADD',
            parentName: 'group',
            parentID: this.props.group.id,

            connectionName: 'blocks',
            edgeName: 'newBlockEdge',
            rangeBehaviors: {
                '': 'append',
            },
        }];
    }


    getOptimisticResponse() {
        return {
            newBlockEdge: {
                node: {
                    body: this.props.body
                }
            },
            group: {
                id: this.props.group.id
            }
        }
    }


    static get fragments() {
        return {
            group: () => Relay.QL`
                fragment on GroupNode {
                    id
                }
            `,
        }
    }
}


class Designer extends React.Component {
    ...

    addToBlocks(blocks) {
        // Create a mutation to save to the blocks.
        Relay.Store.commitUpdate(
            new AddBlock({
                body: blocks[0].block,
                group: this.props.group
            })
        );
    }
    ...
}


Designer = Relay.createContainer(Designer, {
  fragments: {

    group: (Component) => Relay.QL`
      fragment on GroupNode {
        title
        visibility
        blocks(first: 20) {
            edges {
                node {
                    ${Block.getFragment('block')}
                    ${UpdateBlockBodyMutation.getFragment('block')}
                    position
                    title
                }
            }
        }
        ${AddBlock.getFragment('group')}
      }
    `,
  }
});
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: I think the issue might be that the `addToBlocks` function isn't bound to the React component. However you should get some other errors if that was the case..

Comment: @edvinerikson Sadly it seems like it is :( The master React Component is `Designer` that gets rendered by Relay. All fetching is working just fine.

Comment: What does the code that calls `addToBlocks` look like?
And can you try to change

```
    static get fragments() {
        return {
            group: () => Relay.QL
                fragment on GroupNode {
                    id
                }
            ,
        }
    }
```

to

```
    static fragments  = {
            group: () => Relay.QL
                fragment on GroupNode {
                    id
                }
            ,
    }
```

Comment: @edvinerikson Aah the code that calls `addToBlocks` is another unbound component (a popup). Could that be an issue?

Comment: Yes, if it isn't bound the component that calls `Relay.Store.commitUpdate`, `this.props.group` will be undefined. You should do something like this: `this.addToBlocks.bind(this)`, just like you do with React event handlers.

Comment: @edvinerikson Interesting! Now when you say if the component (let's call it component X) isn't bound to the component that calls `Relay.Store.commitUpdate` - which is component Designer - do you mean X's fragments need to be required in Designer's fragments? Or do you simply mean X needs to be a child component to Designer, in a pure React sense?

Comment: @edvinerikson Oh no, `addToBlocks` is already "bound" to this. That's def not an issue. Also, changing the syntax on the mutation didn't work for me. That's just how my babel-webpack-es6 stuff is setup :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your mutation fragment isn't actually being used - you should run a test to see that if you add other fields to the `AddBlock` fragment, you'll find that they aren't being requested...? I'm not 100% sure why (likely something about `static get fragments`), but not quite sure.

Once you get your mutation fragment actually being used, Relay won't complain anymore since it'll be getting data in the correct way :D

Comment: That WAS the problem, @nevilles (@edvinerikson was also right to find it earlier). Nice find! So because this es6 packaging / compiling world is so new to me, I don't know whose fault it is. But everywhere on the web when you search what the equivalent of `static prop = {}` is, you always get this is an ES7 thing, and the es6 version of it is `static get fragment() ..` like this response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420634/static-keyword-throwing-error-in-grunt-babel by the awesome @loganfsmyth. But clearly, to Relay, these don't mean the same thing.

Comment: THIS. For anyone coming here facing this issue, try running your code through the `babel` `stage-0` plugin. The `getFragment` on `Mutation` class does not seem to like the `static get fragments() {...}` definition